# Bundle Identifier differs from prior bundle identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, appstore-approval

So this really put headache on my head and I finally gave up and posted question here. I am trying to update one of my client Application in iTune store and we are facing below error while uploading to App store.

[image: Appstore Error]

So, I already tried couple of solution by creating new app id with the bundle sid id twice. Also delete all old profile etc. But nothing worked yet.

1). iTunes Connect App Bundle ID = 8X8ZP823D6.com.pregnancytoolspro.55freebabysamples
2). Info.plist Bundle ID = com.pregnancytoolspro.55freebabysamples
3). Provision profile ID = 8X8ZP823D6.com.pregnancytoolspro.55freebabysamples

When I Changed Info.plist App ID to **com.pregnancytoolspro.55freebabysamples** then it show me provision profile active in the list.

If I changed Info.plist App ID to **8X8ZP823D6.com.pregnancytoolspro.55freebabysamples** then it doesn't show me provision profile active in the list.

When I build app and upload to App store it pop up this message and I can't understand how it should be in info.plist and in provision profile so that it can match iTunes Bundle ID.

Is anyone faced this problem before ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We contacted Apple support and they said they will have to change Bundle Identifier in the App we have added in our account. So probably Apple will solve this critical issue.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this issue before. It has to do with the different versions saved in the info.plist.

There is a version and build identifier.

[image: version build]

[image]

Apple doesn't really care about the version as much as the build number. If you have submitted your app with a build number, the update must be 1 greater for the update to work. It isn't all that clear how that works, but that is how I got my update to go through. You should be able to find out what these were in iTunesConnect so you can increment them correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But we have correct version and build number. The problem is with bundle ID.